# Why is Mvc SiteMapProvider preservedRouteParameter case sensitive?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, breadcrumbs, mvcsitemapprovider

Currently, I tried out MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC5 4.6.17 to generate breadcrumbs. It works well when I define preservedRouteParameters="**id**" (yeah in route config it's {id} part), but when I change it to preservedRouteParameters="**Id**" - url doesn't match that node.

Is there any reason why it is case sensitive? Is there an easy way to get around it?

Background: in "id" case it doesn't matter as user cannot enter literal 'Id' into url. But I rolled out a way to use querystring parameters but the problem is that querystring value **name** must follow exact casing that is defined in xml config otherwise it doesn't match node.

Comment: FYI - This issue has now been fixed in [v4.6.18](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/releases/tag/v4.6.18), which is available on NuGet.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And url is generated with a casing from mvc.sitemap file.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants to know how I've solved this problem.

The first thing is to extended default SiteMapNode by doing this (2 changes are adding ToLower()):

```
public class CustomSiteMapNode : RequestCacheableSiteMapNode
{
    public CustomSiteMapNode(ISiteMap siteMap, string key, bool isDynamic, ISiteMapNodePluginProvider pluginProvider, IMvcContextFactory mvcContextFactory, ISiteMapNodeChildStateFactory siteMapNodeChildStateFactory, ILocalizationService localizationService, IUrlPath urlPath) :
        base(siteMap, key, isDynamic, pluginProvider, mvcContextFactory, siteMapNodeChildStateFactory, localizationService, urlPath)
    {
    }

    protected override void PreserveRouteParameters()
    {
        if (this.PreservedRouteParameters.Count > 0)
        {
            var requestContext = this.mvcContextFactory.CreateRequestContext();
            var routeDataValues = requestContext.RouteData.Values;
            var queryStringValues = requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString;

            foreach (var item in this.PreservedRouteParameters)
            {
                var preservedParameterName = item.Trim().ToLower();
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(preservedParameterName))
                {
                    if (routeDataValues.ContainsKey(preservedParameterName))
                    {
                        this.routeValues[preservedParameterName] =
                            routeDataValues[preservedParameterName];
                    }
                    else if (queryStringValues[preservedParameterName] != null)
                    {
                        this.routeValues[preservedParameterName] =
                            queryStringValues[preservedParameterName];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override IDictionary<string, object> MergeRouteValuesAndNamedQueryStringValues(IDictionary<string, object> routeValues, ICollection<string> queryStringKeys, HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        // Make a copy of the routeValues. We only want to limit this to the scope of the current node.
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>(routeValues);

        // Add any query string values from the current context
        var queryStringValues = httpContext.Request.QueryString;

        // QueryString collection might contain nullable keys
        foreach (var key in queryStringValues.AllKeys.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList())
        {
            // Copy the query string value as a route value if it doesn't already exist
            // and the name is provided as a match. Note that route values will take
            // precedence over query string parameters in cases of duplicates
            // (unless the route value contains an empty value, then overwrite).
            if (key != null && queryStringKeys.Contains(key) && (!result.ContainsKey(key) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(result[key].ToString())))
            {
                result[key] = queryStringValues[key];
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The next problem was to replace default implementation with this one. The only solution that I could come across was inheriting chain of factories/containers and finally binding it in ninject.

```
public class CustomSiteMapNodeFactory : ISiteMapNodeFactory
public class CustomSiteMapNodeFactoryContainer
internal class CustomSiteMapLoaderContainer

var configSettings = new ConfigurationSettings();
MvcSiteMapProvider.SiteMaps.Loader = new CustomSiteMapLoaderContainer(configSettings).ResolveSiteMapLoader();
```

And finally the attribute that I use to extract property values from model and pass them to parent site map nodes.

```
public class SiteMapRouteValueAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private readonly string _key;
    private readonly string[] _propertyParts;

    public SiteMapRouteValueAttribute(string key, string modelProperty = "")
    {
        _key = key.ToLower();
        _propertyParts = modelProperty.Split(new[] {'.'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    }

    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var viewResult = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (viewResult == null)
        {
            base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
            return;
        }
        var value = viewResult.Model;
        foreach (var property in _propertyParts)
        {
            var propertyInfo = value.GetType().GetProperty(property);
            value = propertyInfo.GetValue(value);
        }
        var currentNode = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;
        while (currentNode != null)
        {
            currentNode.RouteValues[_key] = value;
            currentNode = currentNode.ParentNode;
        }
    }
}
```

So now it works why any case of querystring value names, however siteMap generated url will contain lowercased querystring value names.

Comment: Thanks, I added this as [a bug](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/issues/380). However, the solution I would use would be to add a property that corrects the casing of the values in `requestContext.HttpContext.Request.QueryString` NameValueCollection based on the PreservedRouteParameters. This property would then be used by both `PreserveRouteParameters()` and  'MergeRouteValuesAndNamedQueryStringValues()` to change the casing from the raw URL to what is configured. Then no action filter attribute is necessary.